# Erro NullPointerException ao obter localização

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que mostra as coordenadas do usuário:

Esse funciona corretamente e verifica se o GPS está liberado:

```
public void verificaGPS(){
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //GPS desligado ou sem permissão
        txtLatitude.setText("sem GPS");
    }else{
        //GPS OK
        txtLatitude.setText("com GPS");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        pegaCoord();
    }
}
```

Ele funciona até chamar a função pegaCoord():

```
public void pegaCoord() {
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();

    txtLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + latitude);
    txtLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + longitude);

    try {
        txtCidade.setText("Cidade: " + buscarEndereco(latitude, longitude).getLocality());
        txtEstado.setText("Estado: " + buscarEndereco(latitude, longitude).getAdminArea());
        txtPais.setText("País: " + buscarEndereco(latitude, longitude).getCountryName());
        txtHora.setText("Sol nasce às: " + String.valueOf(horaSol(latitude,longitude)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("GPS", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O erro é:

```
    07-28 17:47:39.497 20924-20924/br.com.wiconsultoria.tattwas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.wiconsultoria.tattwas, PID: 20924
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.wiconsultoria.tattwas/br.com.wiconsultoria.tattwas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference
```

criei a variável na parte de cima, antes de iniciar o código.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Location location;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
```

está certo ou devo fazer diferente?

Podem me ajudar? Abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocorre pois o objeto `Location` está `null`.

Quando ele tenta acessa a variável `location.getLongitude()`, estoura o erro!

Existe uma forma mais atual de pegar a localização que o `locationManager`.

Segue um exemplo:

Adicione a seguinte dependencia no gradle do projeto:

```
dependencies {
.....
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
}
```

Sua Activity:

```
 public class SuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        /**
         * Instacia o GoogleApiClient para obter a localização!
         */
        private void startLocationService(){
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext()).
                    addApi(LocationServices.API).
                    addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).
                    addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                    build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        /**
         * Método é chamado quando o GoogleApiClient se connecta!
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            final LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
            request.setInterval(500); // Intervalo de Atualizações
            request.setPriority(100); //Prioridade
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, request, this);
        }
        /**
         * Método invocado quando a conexão é suspensa!
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            startLocationService();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if(null != mGoogleApiClient){
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Método é chamado toda vez que recebe uma nova Localização!
         * Definido pelo (request.setInterval())
         * @param location
         */
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(null == location){
                return;
            }


            //Aqui você deve chamar seu método pegaCoord();

        }

        /**
         * Invocado quando ocorre um erro ao se conectar!
         */
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult 

connectionResult) {
    }
}
```

Vale lembrar que é necessário adicionar as seguintes permissões em seu `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: consegui resolver com o método que voce me passou. agora como faço pra saber se o aparelho tem GPS e informar ao usuario caso nao tenha?

Comment: Da mesma forma! Veja no método onConnected! É o mesmo q há no seu método verificaGps

Comment: só mais uma pra acabar rsrs: nos testes que fiz, o app roda sem pedir permissão ao usuário para usar a localização. como faço pra informar (ou abrir uma tela), solicitando a permissão pra usar o GPS?

Comment: De uma olhada neste link! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps

Answer (score 3):

Location é null.

Por conta disto isto não irá funcionar:

```
longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Aonde está essa variável `location`?

Acredito que seja esta:

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Se esse for o caso não seria melhor passar essa variável como parâmetro?

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
pegaCoord(location);


public void pegaCoord(Location location) {
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
   // codigo
}
```

Percebi também que Location não foi iniciada. Você tem de se lembrar de iniciar as variáveis:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Location location = new Location();
public LocationManager locationManager = new LocationManager();
public double latitude = new Double();
public double longitude = new Double();
```

Comment: alterei como voce falou e deu o mesmo erro :/

Comment: onde eu incluo => Location location = new Location();

Comment: nao consegui iniciar as variaveis da forma que me passou. ele pediu alguns parametros no Location(...) e nos outros. como ainda sou iniciante, nao consegui fazer funcionar. mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Bom, isso quer dizer que você precisa de algumas coisas para começar a usar a Location. Não sei se é o mesmo comando nas outras IDEs mas no Eclipse se você colocar `Location location = new Location();` e apertar F3 encima de `new "Location()"` ele vai te levar até o construtor da classe e assim você poderá ver que tipo de parâmetro ele espera para ser iniciado.

Comment: To usando o Android Studio

Comment: Talvez seja interessante então dar uma olhada neste [site](http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-tricks-moving-around/), não sei se você já conhece todos os atalhos. E o equivalente do F3 neste caso aparenta ser ctrl+alt+b

Comment: ainda não conheço, estou programando pra android há poucos dias. obrigado pela dica